# ember-cli including different script tags in development vs production

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

when using ember-cli I would like to be able to include an external js library which requires an API key and I would like to use a different API key in development vs production.

Essentially I would like to add the following script tag to app/index.html

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://something.com?key=API_KEY"></script>`

but I would like API_KEY to be different when I'm running in development as opposed to production.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you configure that using environment specific assets? http://www.ember-cli.com/managing-dependencies/#environment-specific-assets

Comment: it isn't clear to me how I would do that, but I'll investigate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [ember-inject-script](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-inject-script) addon which makes it easy to include 3rd party scripts in your ember-cli app. To use it, npm-install the addon then use an initializer to load the script. Then set different values for API_KEY in your [config/environment.js](http://www.ember-cli.com/#Environments)

```
npm install --save-dev ember-inject-script
ember generate initializer something-dot-com
```

Then edit the initializer as follows

```
import injectScript from 'ember-inject-script';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default {
  name: 'something-dot-com',
  initialize: function() {
    var url = "//something.com?key=" + config.SOMETHING_API_KEY;
    injectScript(url);
  };
}
```

And in config/environment.js

```
ENV.SOMETHING_API_KEY = 'YOUR_DEV_API_KEY';

if (ENV.environment === "production") {
  ENV.SOMETHING_API_KEY = 'YOUR_PROD_API_KEY';
}
```

Comment: Mike - does the code above go into into an Ember initializer? If so, what's the benefit over putting it in a `<script>` tag into index.html?

Comment: @chopper yes it goes into an initializer. Not much difference between this and using a script tag, both approaches will work. Main benefit in this case is that you have access to `config` so the script url can change based on environment. Another benefit is that injectScript() returns a promise so you can run something after the script is loaded.